# Microsoft Visual Studio - Default/Auto apply settings?

Tags: c++

How do I auto apply certain settings?
For example:

[image: Properties Page for Platforms Settings]

In this example, I want these settings to stick and not have to reapply them, but if I make a new project I have to constantly reapply them. How do I make them stay in those specific settings?

Comment: Those all go in your `.vcxproj` project file as MSBuild properties - just save a copy and copy+paste it - or make [a proper reusable project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2019). Or make it a reusable `.props` file:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/project-and-solution-files?view=msvc-160 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcxproj-file-structure?view=msvc-160

Comment: Thank you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own template for the wizard, or just modify an existing one.

Here are the steps:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-update-existing-templates?view=vs-2019

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you.

Comment: @ThePlayzPaidOff If this answers your question, please consider accepting it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: It does although I am confused. How do I do that? @Vlad Feinstein

Comment: Nvm figure it out.